# C++ invalid function type casting

Tags: c++, pointer-to-member

I've read several topics about that kind of problem - but can't find a simple and good solution. Here is the code:

```
void SomeFunction() { }

class A {
  public:
    typedef std::function<void(void)> AFunction;
    static void AMethod(AFunction f) { f(); }    
};

class B {
  public:    
    void B1Method() { }        
    void BCorrectCall() { A::AMethod(SomeFunction); }
    void BIncorrectCall() { A::AMethod(B1Method); }
};
```

Problem is here `void BIncorrectCall() { A::AMethod(B1Method); }`, where I receive error about invalid casting. What is the simplest way to achieve that kind of behaviour? Thanks a lot for any advice!

Comment: Lambda was great, thanks to all, problem solved.

Answer (score 2):

Use a lambda:

```
A::AMethod([this]{B1Method();});
```

It doesn't matter in this case, but if you wanted to store `AFunction f` and use it after the call to `AMethod`, you'd have to ensure that the `B` instance (the address of which is saved in the lambda) says alive as long as you use the function.

C++17 allows you to [capture `*this` instead](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda#Lambda_capture), which will copy the entire `B` instance into lambda, but normally it's not what you want.

---

You could do something similar with `std::bind` (see the other answer), but lambdas are more flexible.

Answer (score 2):

`B1Method` is not `void(*)(void)`, it's `void(B1::*)(void)`.

You may do

```
void BIncorrectCall() { A::AMethod(std::bind(&B1::B1Method, this)); }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that `B::B1Method()` is a non-`static` member function in `B` and, therefore, it needs to be called on an instance of `B`.

If the implementation of `B1Method()`  doesn't use any non-`static` data member of `B` and it doesn't call any other non-`static` member function of `B`, then simply declaring it as `static` will work with your current implementation of `BIncorrectCall()` as you will no longer need to call `B1Method()` on an instance of `B`:

```
class B {
  public:    
    static void B1Method() { } // static now      
    void BCorrectCall() { A::AMethod(SomeFunction); }
    void BIncorrectCall() { A::AMethod(B1Method); } // no change
};
```

Otherwise, you have to keep an object of type `B` whenever you want to call `B1::B1Method()`.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to make it `static` and so there is no `this` object, but if you need it (the `this` object), you can use `lambdas`:

```
class B {
public:
    void B1Method() { }
    void BCorrectCall() { A::AMethod(SomeFunction); }
    void BIncorrectCall() {
        std::function<void(void)> el = [&](){this->B1Method();};
        A::AMethod(el);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that 'B1Method' is not a simple function - it's a class method.  That means that when you call `myB.B1Method()`, you're actually calling 'B1Method(&myB)', effectively passing the `this` pointer as a hidden argument - so you can't convert `M1Method` to a `std::function` without specifying which object it should act on.

One approach that should work is using std::bind to construct a callable object from a combination of an object (class instance) and the method.  Something like:

```
void BNowCorrectCall() { A::AMethod(std::bind(&B::B1Method, this)); }
```

Comment: `B1Method(&myB)` is a common way of thinking about member functions, but has no basis in the language definition. It is not how member functions are written or called. In particular, a pointer-to-member-function is **not** a pointer-to-function; it's a completely different beast.